# Why did the hybrid Phillips Curve become flatter (as empirical data shows) after the crisis?

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro, financial-crises

The Phillips Curve equation is:
$$\pi_t=\pi_t^e + \beta_1 (\beta_2 Y_t + (1-\beta_2) Z_t) + \varepsilon_t^\pi$$
where $\pi_t$ is the inflation, $\pi_t^e$ is the expected inflation, $Y_t$ is the output level, $Z_t$ is the real exchange rate, and $\varepsilon_t^\pi$ is a stochastic shock.

In a small open economy (semi-structural framework), the impulse response functions to a domestic demand shock are the following:

[image]

After the crisis, the Phillips Curve became flatter. My question is, how can one interpret the change in the slope of the Phillips Curve after the crisis?

Answer (score 2):

(1) The Phillips curve is not a structural thing, it is not surprising that the relationship between unemployment and inflation is not constant over time.

(2) There's a nice [AER paper](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20150248) by Simon Gilchrist and coauthors that argues that inflation did not go down as much as in earlier recessions because financially constrained firms needed to keep their cash-flows up and increased prices.

Answer (score 1):

After the Financial crisis of 2007–2008, the inflation's decay became more persistent in many countries. There are several reasons why:

- The output gap went below zero in developed economies, however, the inflation level decayed moderately only.
- Changes in the structure of employment. The relative rate of highly educated had increased, therefore, the average level of wages raised as well.
- Fiscal consolidation. The rise of indirect taxation could hold the inflation at extraordinary high level, too.